# Calculate the area of a parametric sector

Tags: definition, circles, angle

I encountered the following definition:

> $\forall tD_t=\{(x,y)\in R^2:\theta(x,y) \in [-\pi,t]\}$ where
>   $\theta(x,y)$ is the angle in $[-\pi,\pi)$ that the vector $(x,y)$
>   forms with the  x-axis.

Now, the goal is to calculate the area $A$ of $D_t$ relatively to a circle with radius $r$, given $t$:

$A = \frac{(t-(-\pi))\frac{r^2}{2}}{\pi r^2}=\frac{t+\pi}{2\pi}$

Well, something here is really odd to me. Why for god sake, is $t-(-\pi)$ represents this angle? I mean, aren't some details missing in order to come up with this conclusion?

Why isn't this angle is simply $t$?

Comment: Begause the area in question is for all directions $\theta$ *between* $-\pi$ and $t$. If you were asked for the length of the interval $[a,b]$, you would answer "$b-a$", not just $b$, wouldn't you?

Comment: @PaulSinclair yeah I would, I guess :(

Comment: The point is $t$ is just the ending angle. The angular width of the sector is the difference between the beginning ($-\pi$) and end ($t$), which is $t - (-\pi)$.